# Typescript, restrain the second parameter to depend on first parameter type

Tags: typescript

I have 2 Object type: TypeA and TypeB
I want to define a function that gets two parameters.
If the first parameter is of type TypeA , then the second can only takes the values 'a' or 'b' 
But if the first parameter is of type TypeB, then the second can only takes the values 'c' or 'd'

```
const A:TypeA =...
const B: TypeB =...

myfunct(A,'a') fine
myfunct(B,'c') fine
myfunct(A,'c') not fine
```

Thx

Comment: you should get familiar with overloads and generics - http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that should do it:

```
interface TypeA { prop1: string }
interface TypeB { prop2: string }
type SmallA = 'a' | 'b';
type SmallB = 'c' | 'd';
interface MixedA {
    prop1: TypeA;
    prop2: SmallA;
}
interface MixedB {
    prop1: TypeB;
    prop2: SmallB;
}

function myFunc(param: MixedA | MixedB) { }

const A: TypeA = { prop1: "w" };
const B: TypeB = { prop2: "w" };

myFunc({ prop1: A, prop2: 'b' })
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: sorry but myFunc({prop1: A, prop2: 'd'}) works, so that's not the answer

Comment: That was happening because the TypeA and TypeB interfaces were empty and they were matching. I have updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Using overloading, you can do this:

```
class TypeA { prop1: string };
class TypeB { prop2: string };

type ab = 'a' | 'b';
type cd = 'c' | 'd';

function func(p1: TypeA, p2: ab): void;
function func(p1: TypeB, p2: cd): void;
function func(p1, p2): void {
    console.log(p1, p2);
}

const ta = new TypeA();
const tb = new TypeB();

func(ta, 'a'); // OK
func(ta, 'b'); // OK
func(tb, 'a'); // NO OK
func(tb, 'c'); // OK
func(ta, 'c'); // NO OK
```