# Typescript only uses first function override

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to make some event overrides so that if the first parameter is something specific, the second parameter will be something specific depending on that first one, but it's only using the first, the code where the overloads are is this:

```js
interface EventListeners<T> {
    (event: "channelUpdate", listener: (channel: AnyGuildChannel, oldChannel: GenericOldChannel) => void): T;
    (event: "channelUpdate", listener: (channel: TextChannel, oldChannel: OldTextChannel) => void): T;
    (event: "channelUpdate", listener: (channel: VoiceChannel, oldChannel: OldVoiceChannel) => void): T;
    (event: "channelUpdate", listener: (channel: CategoryChannel, oldChannel: OldCategoryChannel) => void): T;
    (event: "channelUpdate", listener: (channel: NewsChannel, oldChannel: OldNewsChannel) => void): T;
    (event: "channelUpdate", listener: (channel: StoreChannel, oldChannel: OldStoreChannel) => void): T;
}
```

I've put the interface definitions [here](https://pastebin.com/vhaPRFbk), and the full definitions [here](https://github.com/DonovanDMC/eris/blob/patch-9/index.d.ts). The "full" code isn't mine, it's all a public module, and it's a bit outdated. The issue here is the first interface is the only interface being used. People are wanting to be able to use `instanceof` to change which overload they are using.
The first parameter is working just fine ([example](https://butts-are.cool/Code_-_Insiders_ZvftynxoKv.png)).
The second parameter uses the first overload no matter what I've tried ([example](https://butts-are.cool/Code_-_Insiders_UJ0LxEIgZl.png)).
I'm not fully sure what I'm meant to do here, I've tried a few things like combining the listener overloads into one definition, but that results in `any`, and everything else ends up with the same result as the examples.

Comment: Please consider providing a [mcve] in the text of the question itself, suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE to demonstrate your issue.  Pictures of code and external links are possibly useful supplements, but should not be used in lieu of a self-contained text-based example in the question itself (see the guidelines for [ask]).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript, restrain the second parameter to depend on first parameter type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49690201/typescript-restrain-the-second-parameter-to-depend-on-first-parameter-type)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a single object parameter instead of positional parameters:

```js
type ChannelUpdateProps =
  | { channel: AnyGuildChannel; oldChannel: GenericOldChannel }
  | { channel: TextChannel; oldChannel: OldTextChannel }
  | { channel: VoiceChannel; oldChannel: OldVoiceChannel }
  | { channel: CategoryChannel; oldChannel: OldCategoryChannel }
  | { channel: NewsChannel; oldChannel: OldNewsChannel }
  | { channel: StoreChannel; oldChannel: OldStoreChannel }

interface EventListeners<T> {
  (event: 'channelUpdate', listener: (props: ChannelUpdateProps) => void): T
}
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49690749/1763012) for more.